# How to set change tracking context when deleting rows in batch with CTE?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 and want to set change tracking context for certain delete SQLs. The DELETE SQL uses CTE to delete rows in small batches to avoid lock escalation:

```
WITH cte_rows_to_delete (id) AS   
(
     SELECT TOP 100 id 
     FROM TableA
)
DELETE FROM cte_rows_to_delete;
```

I am able to set change tracking context for DELETE without CTE:

```
DECLARE @dc varbinary(128) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), N'UseCaseA');
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT (@dc) DELETE FROM TableA
```

But when I put them together,

```
DECLARE @dc varbinary(128) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), N'UseCaseA');

WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT (@dc) 
WITH cte_rows_to_delete (id) AS   
(
     SELECT TOP 100 id 
     FROM TableA
)
DELETE FROM cte_rows_to_delete;
```

I got an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

If I add a `;` in front of the CTE, SQL Server simply complains about

> Incorrect syntax near ';'

My question is: can SQL Server CTE be used together with the change tracking context clause? I googled but was not able to find any any documents with a definitive answer.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite baffling that this syntax isn't documented for the statements to which it applies! `WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT` has its own topic, but that doesn't explain how it's supposed to integrate in all statements.

From my experiments, it appears you use it in much the same way as you would declare multiple CTEs in a single statement:

```
WITH 
    CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT (@dc),
    cte_rows_to_delete (id) as ( SELECT TOP 100 id from TableA) 
DELETE FROM cte_rows_to_delete;
```

At least, this syntax gives no error for me in SQL Server 2017; I haven't tested it against an actual database with change tracking enabled.

Of note is that the order of `WITH` clauses is not free: `WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT` must appear first, then any `XMLNAMESPACES` declaration, then any CTEs. If there are more `WITH`s I'm not familiar with, they probably have a fixed order too.

Comment: I tested this on SQL Server 2016 and confirmed this is the correct syntax. It's the same syntax as specifying multiple CTEs by separating them with a comma, with the added constraint you mentioned about `change_tracking_context` having to be first.